# Can't use varien

Tags: magento

In the template register.phtml I added an input type radio for some terms and condition agreements.
This one is required.

I didn't success to use the javascript Magento’s frontend validation. I add all sort of classes but nothing worked.

Is Someone knows how to do please ? thanks

Here the html

```
<div class="field radiobox">
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="radio" name="accept" title="<?php echo $this->__('I Agree to our Terms & Conditions') ?>" id="accept"  class="radio required-entry validate-one-required-by-name validation-passed validation-failed" >
        <label for="accept" class=required" ><?php echo $this->__('I Agree to our Terms & Conditions') ?></label>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        new Varien.FileElement('accept');
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly your register file look?

Comment: have you removed this new Varien.FileElement('accept'); or not?

Comment: So it should work. in my form its working fine have you find any javascript error in console?

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove all class other then required-entry

```
<input type="radio" name="accept" title="<?php echo $this->__('I Agree to our Terms & Conditions') ?>" id="accept"  class="radio required-entry" >
```

And put this in your form tag, you don't need to create any javascript for this just ensure that it is under form tag, in register.phtml file magento already define validation javascript so don't put your javascript again.

Comment: Thanks Mufaddal for your answer but unfortunatly this doesn't walk.

Comment: ok I had deleted the script which instancied the varien validation.

Answer (score 0):

@Mufaddal

```
<div class="account-form-wrapper registerpass">
            <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="ctools-use-modal-processed" novalidate="novalidate">
                <div class="fieldset">
                    <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />
                </div>
<?php  echo  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>

                <div class="field">
                    <label for="email_address" class="required"><em>*</em>Email Address</label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__("Email Address") ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" placeholder="Password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="confirmation" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="password" name="confirmation" title="<?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?>" id="confirmation" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="field radiobox">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="radio" name="accept" title="<?php echo $this->__('I Agree to our Terms & Conditions') ?>" id="accept"  class="radio required-entry" >
                        <label for="accept" class=required" ><?php echo $this->__('I Agree to our Terms & Conditions') ?></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

__('Submit') ?>" id="form-submit">
                            __('maak mijn profiel aan') ?>

```
                </form>
```